# Checking whether a parameter belongs to a type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typechecking

How can I check whether a certain parameter belongs to a type I've defined in TypeScript?
For example:

```
type myType = {n:number}
let par = {n:3}
```

I want to check whether `x` is of the type `mtType`. If I use `typeof par` the returned value of it is the string `"object"`. Thanks.

Comment: While the duplicate does not have an answer marked, the I stand by my  answer there. The gist of it is, types are erased, check if properties are present and of the expected type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [type guards](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) section here. It is possible with the following syntax:

```
function isMyType(arg: any): arg is myType {
    // you can replace the following expression with the logic 
    // that clearly defines that if an object can be myType
    return arg.n !== undefined && arg.n === parseInt(arg.n);
}
```

and later in the code

```
if (isMyType(objectToCheck)){
   // do something with the object as myType
}
```

Comment: Why not `typeof(arg.n) === "number"`? I don't see OP saying that `{n:3.14}` is not a `myType`.

Comment: makes sense but the question (and the answer) is related to the object type checking instead of the field value type. Anyways, i will add a comment to clarify that.